# Are there application specific MRU's in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

One of my common actions in Windows 7 was to RDP from home to work. My workflow was Pin "Remote Desktop Connection" to my start menu, and click on the only MRU connection (my work computer).

As it was the only machine I RDP'd to it was always there.

Is there anything similar in Windows 8 using the Start Menu, I know I "could" use the taskbar if I wanted, but I quite liked what I had. Or is there a better workflow I should be using now I'm on Windows 8?

By MRU I am referring to the "Recent" list as in this example (just found on google).
[image]

Comment: Windows 8 doesn't have a "Start Menu" anymore, it' snow the Start Screen.  So exactly what is it in Windows 8 you want to be able to click on?  Why not just save and make a Shortcut to the one RDP server you use and put that where you want on the Start Menu?

Comment: Also, when you open the Remote Desktop Client, it contains a history of the servers you've connected to, so I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: @techie007 OK, that wasn't as easy to do as I thought, but with a bit of googling I found out how to add a shortcut to the start screen :)

Comment: @DaveShaw: If you answered your own question, perhaps you can post the answer below so future readers can easily use the same solution you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could come up with was @techie007's suggestion in the comments. There is no real way to do this in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

There are a few third-party tools out there that allows you to get back your start menu and recent files items.

1. Pokki Start Menu
2. Vistart
3. Classic Shell
4. Power8
5. Start Menu X

I'm [personally](http://darktips.com/start-menu-in-windows-8/) using Classic Shell. It's free and stable that the others.

**Solution 2:**

Another solution would be to access the RDP with these shortchuts :
From the Metro Interface, Click <kbd>Windows</kbd>  + <kbd>R</kbd> to bring the RUN Command and Type **MSTSC**.

**Solution 3:**

Create a RDP connection shortcut by following solution 2. On the Remote Desktop Connection windows, Click on "**General**" tab and in click "**Save as**" in the **connection settings**. This will save a .rdp file to a location of your choice. You then need to open this .rdp file each time you want to remote desktop to specific computer.